# NFC tag changed its available technologies (IsoDep, NfcA and Ndef to only IsoDep and NfcA)

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I'm working on an Android application to interface between a mobile phone and a specific chip that supports NFC, which is called the NF4 chip and is manufactured by EM Microelectronic. Here is a link to the datasheet of this chip: http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/sites/default/files/public/products/datasheets/nf4-fs.pdf

In page 3 of the datasheet, the memory system of the chip is summarized. Part of what I need to do is to create a file in the memory and write to it. I was working on this and testing it using a phone and the NFC tag.

To achieve what I need, the app sends the following APDUs to the chip:

- select an EF in the memory system (Select File APDU)
- write to this file (Update Binary APDU)

The chip comes with other NFC tags/cards that are basically the same as this chip, only without the serial interface.

One time I was testing my app with one of the extra tags (cards). The tag stopped functioning as it used to. An application made by EM Microelectronic (who make the tag) used to be able to read and write to the tag, but after this incident the EM app stopped being able to do this.

When I looked into the matter further, I found that the technologies of the tag went from being (IsoDep, NfcA and Ndef) in the beginning to only (IsoDep and NfcA) after that one testing session with my app. Therefore, it is basically not an NFC-Forum supported tag anymore.

I'm not sure what happened and need to solve this problem and return the tag to its previous state. I also need to understand what my app did to the tag to cause it to become like this so that I can stop it from happening when I test again.

One theory that I thought of is that maybe when my app selected an EF that isn't a child of the DF that stores the NFC data in the tag, this is what caused the problem. That is, the NFC Dedicated File is still in memory but is not selected as the current file... I'm not sure if this could actually cause the problem that I described.

Does this make sense, or could it be something else?